# Add custom widget in Shopify

Tags: jquery, widget, shopify

I have a Shopify store and I tried adding a widget that uploads images by user
via this the widget:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

1. I added this code for page.liquid:

   ```html
   <head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   {{ 'jquery.ui.widget.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
   {{ 'jquery.fileupload.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
   {{ 'jquery.iframe-transport.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
   </head>
   <div id="content">
      <div class="container">

   <div class="title clearfix">

   </div>

   <div class="page_content">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
         <div class="sfbox box-page animated rollIn" data-animation="rollIn">
           <div class="rte">
   <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>


    <script>
     $(function () {
   $('#fileupload').fileupload({
       dataType: 'json',
       add: function (e, data) {
           data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
               .appendTo(document.body)
               .click(function () {
                   data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                   data.submit();
               });
       },
       done: function (e, data) {
           data.context.text('Upload finished.');
       }
   });
    });
    </script>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. I uploaded 4 files of js to Assets :

   - jquery.fileupload.js.liquid
   - jquery.iframe-transport.js.liquid
   - jquery.ui.widget.js.liquid
   - main.js
3. [image: this screen shot of page]
4. In file that contains the widget I have a folder of "server/php"
   and in Shopify I can't upload this folder.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Shopify doesn't handle PHP files. In addition you can create a image upload field for the user in the front-end without an APP.

Comment: @drip I want to upload files and save by cookies , So how do I do this without APP?

Comment: @drip that the user upload file to area "upload images" in my site